How can I get USD price of a Pumpfun token without using an API?
I am able to get info of a pumpfun token using getAccountInfo on the bonding curve address, but it does not contain the USD price of the token.
This is the code I have so far to get pumpfun token info
export const getPumpfunBondingCurveAccountData = async(wallet: Wallet, mint: PublicKey) => {

    const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, { commitment: "confirmed" })
    const pumpfunProgram = new Program<PumpFun>(IDL as PumpFun, provider)

    // get bonding curve PDA
    const bondingCurvePDA = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [Buffer.from(PUMPFUN_BONDING_CURVE_SEED), mint.toBuffer()],
        pumpfunProgram.programId
    )[0]
    const tokenAccount = await connection.getAccountInfo(bondingCurvePDA, "processed")
    if (!tokenAccount) {
        console.log(`Token account not found for pumpfun token ${mint.toBase58()}`)
        return
    }
    console.log(`Token account owner:${tokenAccount.owner.toBase58()}`)
    let bondingCurveAccount = BondingCurveAccount.fromBuffer(tokenAccount.data)
    console.log("-- Bonding Curve Account ---")
    console.log(bondingCurveAccount)
    return bondingCurveAccount
}

This outputs an info like the following in the console
Token account owner:6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P
-- Bonding Curve Account ---
BondingCurveAccount {
  discriminator: 6966180631402821399n,
  virtualTokenReserves: 936194487413872n,
  virtualSolReserves: 34383881167n,
  realTokenReserves: 656294487413872n,
  realSolReserves: 4383881167n,
  tokenTotalSupply: 1000000000000000n,
  complete: false
}

Is there any way I can get the USD price or USD marketcap of the token from this data?
